# Is there a way to manually create log files for certain task scheduler tasks?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-task-scheduler

I want to log the exact time when certain scheduler tasks run and finish.

I've tried playing around with enabling history, but it seems I need to enable for all tasks? I didn't see an option to select history for individual tasks. 
Also, it seems history creates 4 logs files per each run of  task?
(BTW where are the history log files stored)
That would eat up my disk space slow and steadily. 
Lastly, history uses a lot of cryptic numeric codes that make the info harder to decipher.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run the task inside another, such as .BAT file, that writes the time before the task starts and again after the task completes. It might be better to do this as a small console application, if a .BAT file does not run in Scheduled Tasks.